# Render only selected part of ngTemplateOutlet in Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to be able to select part of `ngTemplateOutlet` that I want to render.

On an example:

**[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-77v7sw)**

```
main.component.html

<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="myTemplate"></ng-container>
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="myTemplate"></ng-container>
```

```
main.component.ts

  selector: 'app-main',

  @ContentChild(
    MyDirective,
    {read: TemplateRef, static: false}
  ) myTemplate;
```

```
my-directive.directive.ts


@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]'
})
export class MyDirective{}
```

```
example.component.html

<app-main>
  <div *myDirective> AAA </div>
  <div *myDirective> BBB </div>
</app-main>
```

If I run this code and check it in browser - I get:

```
<div>AAA</div>
<div>AAA</div>
```

While I would like to get this:

```
<div>AAA</div>
<div>BBB</div>
```

Can I achive this somehow?

I'm getting double "AAA" probably because `*ngTemplateOutlet` just catches the first `*myDirective` and passes it.

Can I somehow select which of `*myDirective` I want to get?

Maybe there's something like...

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="myTemplate" getContentBy='.classBBB'></ng-container>
```

```
<div *myDirective class='classBBB'> BBB </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this case I would make a component not a directive, you'll need to use

```
<my-component> AAA </my-component>
<my-component> BBB </my-component>
```

In the HTML template from the component:

```
<ng-content></ng-content> <!-- <<<<<<<< THE CONTENT WILL BE RENDERED HERE -->
```

This way you can also pass parameters as attributes.

```
<my-component myAttr="someVar"> AAA </my-component>
```

and in your component you get it as an @Input()

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html'
})
export class myComponent{

    @Input('auto') auto = true;

    constructor(){}
}
```

Hope this helps!

Edit: Typo